# ASP.NET root path

Tags: asp.net, path, root

I have my app written with all the links relative to the root path. Now, when I upload it to the server, the server has two additional levels like /apps/thisapp/ so all my links(those not run on server) get broken..is there a fast way to fix it?

Comment: I assume you mean the application's root path?

Comment: yes. all app's links are set to root path, but there's two more levels on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all your links to resolve to the root, you could do it server-side with:

```
<img src="~/apps/thisapp/images/logo.gif" alt="" runat="server" />
```

The combination of the root tilde operator ("~/") and the runat attribute will ensure server-side resolution of the link.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably not a good fast way to fix it without going through each relative URL.  Generally, you'll want to use [Url.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx).

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/logo.gif") %>"/>
```