# adding images to a build c#

Tags: c#, image, build

What is the best way to add an image to the actual build of a project?

I currently have it so it the file path of the image is being referenced, but if I were to
send my build to another computer the file path of the image would change for obvious reasons.

So the question I am trying to ask is how would i generalize a file path to maybe just a folder that is containing my .exe, or even building the files into the .exe if that is even possible?

If it helps I am using Microsoft Visual Studios 2010.

Comment: Take a look at this link:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798327/asp-net-root-path

Comment: What type of project? Web Site? Winform? console app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an image as an Embedded Resource as part of your exe. You could then use Reflection via [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) to access the image as a stream and create a bitmap out of the stream.

Comment: Right click the Resources folder in the Solution Explorer and select Add, Existing Item... and browse to the image.

Answer (score 0):

## Adding a resource

You need to add a resource in your c# application, you can achieve that by creating an [`ItemGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) in your csproj file.

```xml
<Project>
  <!-- rest of your csproj file -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="YourResource.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- rest of your csproj file -->
</Project>
```

Now you can load your resource as [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-7.0) in your program using [`GetManifestResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=net-7.0).

```cs
namespace Application;

public static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        // The resource will be declared in the namespace.
        // Assuming the resource is in the root of your project
        Stream image 
            = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Application.YourResource.png")!;

        // you can now use your image as a stream in your application.
        image./*...*/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a subdirectory in the application installed directory. The relative path can be configured in app.config file.

or, you can create satellite assembly and include images in satellite assembly as resources.